# ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, casting, adapter

I keep getting a runtime error when I try to launch an activity.

Line where the error happen:

```
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        textView1.setText("Csatlakozás...");
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString(); // <-- ERROR HERE
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
        Intent i = new Intent(DeviceListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

Logcat:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView
>                                                                                            at
>   arduinosensors.example.com.smarthome3.DeviceListActivity$1.onItemClick(DeviceListActivity.java:106)

What is happening here? It was fine until I started to use a custom array adapter with custom row layout.

Edit:

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Adapter> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Adapter> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Adapter user = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater sontInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = sontInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
        }

        TextView one = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        one.setText(user.name);
        two.setText(user.hometown);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild?

Comment: @tyczj Yes, didn't work

Comment: post more code for  better understanding

Comment: I've have added the relevant codes, but theres a link for the full project too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html):

> View: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a
>   view provided by the adapter)

In your case the `View` is the root `ConstraintLayout`. And as the error says you can't cast it to `TextView`. To get the info you can use:

`String info = v.findViewById(R.id.textView).getText().toString()`

Comment: Works well thanks! Anyway getText() doesnt work here

Comment: Maybe you need to cast it to `TextView`

Comment: Yeah just figured it out, Thanks, you guys are really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You just got wrong id for your constrain layout and mixed it up with textview that you have make declaration in MainActivity