# My Android App crashes when I hit the button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I was following a tutorial video on youtube for creating a simple Android App. There are two number input boxes, one multiply button and one textView box for displaying the result. When I hit the multiply button, the app should multiply the two numbers that user entered and display the result. But when I hit the multiply button, the app crashes. Couldn't figure out why. I selected Android 8.0, while creating the project. Layout : https://ibb.co/PtcPCFc

```
    package com.sa.firstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button multiplyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyButton);
        multiplyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
                EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);

                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumEditText.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumEditText.getText().toString());

                int result = num1 * num2;
                resultTextView.setText(String.valueOf(result));

            }
        });
            }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
     --------- beginning of crash
2020-06-24 21:31:02.754 8724-8724/com.sa.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sa.firstapp, PID: 8724
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.sa.firstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7438)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7415)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28286)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
2020-06-24 21:31:02.814 8724-8724/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8724 SIG: 9
```

Here is a screenshot of the app:
[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqQgE.png)

Comment: Show us your layout file

Comment: I'm sorry just downloaded the Android Studio today, where can I find the layout file?

Comment: the place where you've placed the button and texts :)

Comment: Not an expert but there should be an "firstNumEditText" and its not inside the EditText

Comment: here is the layout, I hope this is it: https://ibb.co/PtcPCFc

Comment: can you explain this exactly where? " there should be an "firstNumEditText" and its not inside the EditText"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702186/constraintlayout-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-textview). Check your layout file for something with an ID of `firstNumEditText`. It looks like that's currently a `ConstraintLayout` element, but you're trying to cast it to an `EditText`, which is why you're getting this error. Basically, the element type in your layout needs to match the type you're casting it to in the Activity.

Comment: Also, welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include the actual code rather than screenshots of code hosted at potentially sketchy websites.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my question, there was a another thing named firstNumEditText. I corrected it and problem solved. Thanks Joao and Steven Jones and Ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a ClassCastException.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.EditText

In your code, one of the two EditText

> EditText firstNumEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
> EditText secondNumEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);

that you are binding is referring to an ID that belongs to the ConstraintLayout as opposed to an EditText. In the image that you have posted, **R.id.secondNumEditText** belongs to the ConstraintLayout. Click the EditText in your layout and it will show in the right panel what id you have to use in Java.